# Changing the appearance of the login and URL of Cloudtrax for client access

Tags: networking, interface, skin

**Background:** We currently manage a wireless network for a store, which is used by its customers when they want free Wi-Fi which we control using Cloudtrax linked to our Open-Mesh access points.

**Requirement:** The client wants to have control via this interface, but we don’t want the client to see that they are using Cloudtrax, we want to “skin” the login and admin pages so that they see only our branding, and our URL, thus not leaving even a mention of Cloudtrax.

**Question:** How would I go about doing something like this?

*Thanks in advance for anything helpful! it's much appreciated*

Answer (score -1):

loudtrax offers the ability to add a custom logo to your Cloudtrax network. This logo will be seen when you or your customers log in to Cloudtrax, as well as on any vouchers you may decide to print. By default, this will be set as the default Cloudtrax logo.

Follow these steps to change your network logo:

Log into your Cloudtrax network.
Navigate to “Edit Network”, which can be found in the top right hand corner of the Cloudtrax login page.
In the top left corner, you will see the Cloudtrax logo, with the word “replace” that is green and underlined. Click “replace”.
After you have clicked the link, a “browse” button will appear. Simply click this button, and navigate to the image you have saved. After you have selected the image, hit “submit”.
If everything has gone correctly, you should see your updated logo where the Cloudtrax logo was previously located.
There are some restrictions on the logo: it can be no larger than 100K, and must be a supported file type such as png, jpg, or gif. If these requirements are not met, you will be displayed an error stating that your image does not meet the requirements, and the logo will be reset to Cloudtrax.

Logos are set on a per-network basis. If you have multiple networks, you'll have to upload a custom logo for each one.

Comment: Hi Niall, Thanks for responding to my question, whilst that's great to change the logo, there is other cloudtrax branding and of course still the URL is an issue.